# Save in DB a Progress Scrollbar value(%) when user automatically closes the page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, progress-bar, scrollbar

I'm working on a progress scrollbar, and I'm trying to save the value(%) in the database/Mysql automatically where each user leaves on the page when closing it.

Ex.: A user accessed the page and scrolled down to 79% and closed the page, so in my MySQL database it will be registered this value 79% (only the value, nothing about the user)... And so to other users successively to that specific page.

I tryied session, but could only save with the automatic save after a programed time, here's what i have:

index.html:

```
    <div class="progress position-sticky">
        <div class="progress-bar" id="myProgressBar"  role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container text">
        <h1>Bootstrap Reading Progressbar Example</h1>
        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt autem ex illum voluptates officiis earum, odit explicabo repellat ducimus modi excepturi libero officia soluta doloremque voluptatum numquam eligendi quibusdam fugiat. Voluptatem incidunt ipsum nam quisquam repellendus distinctio minus doloribus corporis aspernatur. Sunt omnis repudiandae in illum unde nisi id culpa temporibus, voluptatem aut nobis doloremque optio impedit quidem porro ad rerum qui placeat magnam quod quae maiores deserunt! Soluta aliquid numquam sapiente quasi molestias, nulla magnam illo odio voluptatum sint obcaecati eos odit officia per ....... </p>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

        function myFunction() {
          var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
          var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
          var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
          document.getElementById("myProgressBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
          document.getElementById("myProgressBar").innerHTML= Math.round(scrolled) + "%";
        }
    </script>
```

save_post.php

```
    <?php  
     $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
     if(isset($_POST["postTitle"]) && isset($_POST["postDescription"]))
     {
      $post_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["postTitle"]);
      $post_description = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["postDescription"]);
      if($_POST["postId"] != '')  
      {  
        //update post  
        $sql = "UPDATE tbl_post SET post_title = '".$post_title."', post_description = '".$post_description."' WHERE post_id = '".$_POST["postId"]."'";  
        mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
      }  
      else  
      {  
        //insert post  
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_post(post_title, post_description, post_status) VALUES ('".$post_title."', '".$post_description."', 'draft')";  
        mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
        echo mysqli_insert_id($connect);  
      }
     }  
     ?>
```

Database:

```
     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_post` (  
      `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
      `post_title` text NOT NULL,  
      `post_description` text NOT NULL,  
      `post_status` varchar(15) NOT NULL,  
      PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`)  
     ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

But what I need is a system that saves the value automatically where the value(%) of the progress scrollbar stands after the user closes the browser, not time to time when the user still on the page (as this current codes).

Comment: `window.onbeforeunload = saveProgress` ;)

Comment: @HagaiWild Sorry friend, i got ask: Should i replace `window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};` for what you sugest? Thank you